# Finding two sided bounds on $(x+y)/(xy)$ given inequalities for $x$ and $y$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Given $\dfrac{1}{6} < x < \dfrac{1}{2}$ and $\dfrac{1}{7} < y < \dfrac{1}{3}$,
can we determine bounds for $\dfrac{x+y}{xy}$?

Comment: Is it $x+\frac{y}{x}\cdot y$ or $x+\frac{y}{xy}?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean determine bounds on $\frac{x+y}{xy}$, then this is what would be done:

$\frac{x+y}{xy}=\frac{x}{xy}+\frac{y}{xy}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}$

Then $\frac{1}{6} < x < \frac{1}{2}\implies6 > \frac{1}{x} > 2,\: \:\frac{1}{7} < y < \frac{1}{3}\implies7 > \frac{1}{y} > 3$

Adding these inequalities together, $13>\frac{x+y}{xy}>5$

Comment: Answer is true .Thanks :)